# How can i repeat a script for each row in a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, spreadsheet

I'm making a script that visits a page and scrapes some data. The URL for this page is loaded from a Google Spreadsheet. I want to repeat this script for each cell with text in Column A.

Column A has various rows that all contain a different URL:
A1: https://www.bol.com/nl/p/m-line-athletic-pillow/9200000042954350/?suggestionType=typedsearch&bltgh=oOLF6wrL80g-ozfXiYFIZg.1.2.ProductImage
A2: https://www.bol.com/nl/p/apollo-bonell-matras-90x200-cm-medium/9200000046271731/?suggestionType=typedsearch&bltgh=i745aole4Xm4c6Gl23BM3w.1.2.ProductTitle
A3: etc
...

The script works only on A1, how can I customise it so it repeats on all rows? Please help!

I was thinking of creating a 'for loop' but it isn't working.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import datetime
import re

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("/Users/Jeffrey/Downloads/bolscraper.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("Scraper")
results = sheet.sheet1
itemList = sheet.worksheet('LoadThisList')
date = str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))


def inject_scraping():
   browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Jeffrey/Downloads/chromedriver')
   browser.get(itemlist.acell('A1').value)
   time.sleep(1)
   browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quantityDropdown"]').send_keys('5')
   time.sleep(1)
   browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quantityDropdown"]').send_keys('meer')
   time.sleep(1)
   browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.text-input--two-digits').click()
   time.sleep(0.5)
   browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.text-input--two-digits').send_keys('00')
   time.sleep(0.5)
   browser.find_element_by_link_text('OK').click()
   time.sleep(0.5)
   browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("In winkelwagen").click()
   time.sleep(2)
   page_source = browser.page_source
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
   browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.modal__window--close-hitarea').click()
   page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
   seller = page_soup.select_one('div.buy-block__seller > div > a')
   sellertext = seller.findAll(text=True)
   sellername = str(sellertext)
   actualseller = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9\s:]", "", sellername)
   bucket = page_soup.select_one('#basket')
   bucketnumber = bucket.findAll(text=True)
   bucketDef = str(bucketnumber)
   bucketactual = re.sub("\D", "", bucketDef)

   producttitle = page_soup.select_one('body > div.main > div > div.constrain.constrain--main.h-bottom--m > div.pdp-header.slot.slot--pdp-header.js_slot-title > h1 > span')
   producttitleText = producttitle.findAll(text=True)
   producttitleDef = str(producttitleText)
   actualproducttitle = re.sub("[\[\]\']", "", producttitleDef)
   productprice = page_soup.select_one('body > div.main > div.product_page_two-column > div.constrain.constrain--main.h-bottom--m > div.\[.fluid-grid.fluid-grid--rwd--l.\].new_productpage > div:nth-child(2) > div.slot.slot--buy-block.slot--seperated > div > wsp-visibility-switch > section > section > div > div > span')
   productpriceText = productprice.findAll(text=True)
   productpriceDef = str(productpriceText)
   actualprice = re.sub("[\D]", "", productpriceDef)

   newRow = [date, actualseller, bucketactual, actualprice, actualproducttitle]
   results.append_row(newRow)
inject_scraping()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion to use a for-loop should get the job done. Put all the cell-names in a list and loop through that list like below

**NOTE**: make sure to replace the hardcoded cellname 'A1' with 'cell' (as defined in the loop) otherwise it will still only run for that single (hard-coded) cell. You might have forgotten this step earlier.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import datetime
import re

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("/Users/Jeffrey/Downloads/bolscraper.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("Scraper")
results = sheet.sheet1
itemList = sheet.worksheet('LoadThisList')
date = str(datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))

cells = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

def inject_scraping():
    for cell in cells:
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Jeffrey/Downloads/chromedriver')
        browser.get(itemlist.acell(cell).value)
        ## ... Rest of your scraper code ...
        browser.close()
```

In extention you can write a similar function to fill the 'cells' list so you don't have to put them hard-coded like above.

Make sure you put in a `browser.close()` to close the webdriver. Or even better would be to define a class with `setup()` and `teardown()` method where you can define these things.